# iOS 11, Status bar, Navigation Bar and UIScrollview

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, snapkit

I was making some updates to an app for iOS 11 and have run into something I cannot make sense of.  My view controller creates all of its subviews programmatically.

The first child is an Imageview.  On top of that I add a UIScrollView.  Within the scroll view there is a UIView and within that a label.  I'm using SnapKit for Autolayout constraints via code.

iOS 9 and iOS 10 work great - no issues.  In iOS 11, however, it *appears* to work fine until I "pull down" on the scroll view.  Instead of bouncing back to its original position as iOS 9 and 10 do, it stays scrolled down as if the insets were about 2x what they actually are.

[image: What it looks like]

```
// Scroll View
myScrollView = UIScrollView()
myScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollInsetHeight(), 0, 0, 0)
myScrollView.backgroundColor = barBackgroundColor
myScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(myScrollView)
myScrollView.snp.makeConstraints {
    make in
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
}

// Content View
contentView = UIView()
contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
myScrollView.addSubview(contentView)
contentView.snp.makeConstraints {
    make in
    make.edges.equalTo(myScrollView)
    make.width.equalTo(self.view)
}

// Label
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.text = "..."

lbl.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)
lbl.textColor = .white
lbl.numberOfLines = 0

contentView.addSubview(lbl)
lbl.snp.makeConstraints {
    make in
    make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
    make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
}

// Resize Content
contentView.snp.makeConstraints {
    make in
    make.bottom.equalTo(lbl.snp.bottom).offset(20)
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Pretty simple fix using the new UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    myScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
}
```

Comment: You saved my day!=)

Comment: @SatnamSync May I recommend opting for a somewhat higher level of language? The polite word you were looking for is probably "annoying".

Comment: @Yunnosch The language level is just fine. And sorry for that, if it offends you in some way.